# Product List Esi Cache Policy Turpentine

Tags: cache, product-list, turpentine

I'm trying to implement an esi cache policy for Product List in Turpentine.
I have Magento 1.9.1.0.
This is the code I used:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setEsiOptions">
                <params>
                    <access>private</access>
                    <registry_keys>
                        <current_category/>
                    </registry_keys>
                </params>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
```

This code works when I load product list. 
I have problem when I filter the list with custom attributes. In this case I always see list filtered with current category.
What code I should add to see list filtered by attributes?

Thanks

Comment: Can you rephrase your question Andrea? Specifically "In this case I always see list filtered with current category."

Comment: If I load a category page, i will see a product list correctly. The problem is that if I filter this list with custom attributes i will see the same product list as before.

Comment: It only happens with custom attributes?

Comment: It happens with all the attribute i use in layered navigation, for example manufacturer, color ecc...

Comment: aa?! you dont have to do this, you dont have to set any special policy for category page, Varnish caches all by URL, so there is something wrong with your attributes, what is your filtered url looks like??

Comment: my filtered url is "www.mysite.com/women-bags?manufacturer=1000"... I set a policy for category page because I defined a rule that different customer group can view different products in the category... So category page will be different for each customer group